# Why is $ \lim_{x\to 25}(25−x)/(\sqrt x−5)= -10$?

Tags: calculus, limits

I know the answer is $-10$ but I don't know where the negative sign is coming from.

This is what I ended up with.    $$\frac{(x-25)(\sqrt{x}+5)}{x-25}   =  (1)\sqrt x+5 = 10
$$

Like I said I'm not sure where the negative sign comes from.

Comment: Do you mean $$\frac{25-x}{\sqrt{x}-5}?$$ $(x√−5)$ is meaningless.

Comment: You simply flipped the sign. $25-x=-(x-25)$.

Comment: Yes, it is fixed. I did not know how to do that sign.

Comment: Problem solved? It's just sign flipping...

Comment: Um, you do know that when you flip signs the answer flips from neg to pos and back, don't you? x > 25 the 25 - x is neg and sqrt x - 5 is pos so the answer is neg.  if x< 25 then 25 - x is pos and sqrtx -5 is neg so the answer in neg.  So are you still not understanding where the negative came from?

Comment: I didn't know you had to put a negative in front of (x-25) when they switched places.

Comment: @user3552678 they didn't just "switch places." It's not a game with arbitrary rules, the notation is meaningful. You're really multiplying by $-1$.

Answer (score 2):

Notice, negative sign comes from denominator: $x-25=\color{red}{-(25-x)}$ as follows  $$=\lim_{x\to 25}\frac{(25-x)}{\sqrt x-5}$$
$$=\lim_{x\to 25}\frac{(25-x)(\sqrt x+5)}{(\sqrt x-5)(\sqrt x+5)}$$
$$=\lim_{x\to 25}\frac{(25-x)(\sqrt x+5)}{x-25}$$
Taking $-1$ common to make denominator $(25-x)$, 
$$=\lim_{x\to 25}\frac{\color{red}{(25-x)}(\sqrt x+5)}{\color{red}{-(25-x)}}$$
$$=-\lim_{x\to 25}(\sqrt x+5)$$
$$=-(5+5)=\color{red}{-10}$$
**Alternate method:**

$$=\lim_{x\to 25}\frac{(25-x)}{\sqrt x-5}$$
$$\lim_{x\to 25}\frac{\underbrace{25-x}_{\longrightarrow 0}}{\underbrace{\sqrt x-5}_{\longrightarrow 0}}$$
Applying L'Hospital's rule for $\frac 00$ form, 
$$=\lim_{x\to 25}\frac{-1}{\frac{1}{2\sqrt x}}$$
$$=\lim_{x\to 25}(-2\sqrt x)$$
$$=-2(5)=\color{red}{-10}$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: Notice that $$25-x=(5-\sqrt{x})(5+\sqrt{x})$$ Then simply the numerator and the denominator by taking the negative sign